# Cannot register in sample BlackBerry push application

Tags: api, blackberry, push

I am developing a BlackBerry application in which I need to use PUSH API. I already have registered with RIM and they have sent me the credentials for evaluation service. In my BlackBerry device, I installed sample push API application just to test that the push messaging works. After setting the content provider URL which is publicly accessible, I entered all the details for the sample application to register the it for receiving notification messages. When trying to register it asks for username and password but I don't know what they are for. In the email received from RIM, there are passwords for server application and content provider admin portal applications but not for the push client.

When I added an arbitrary username and password it fails with the message that java.lang.Exception Registration with Push API failed, caused by **port is unavailable**. But when I unregister it successfully unregisters the user with the given arbitrary username and password. By the I use the port given in the RIM's email.

I have no idea why this happens and I appreciate immediate response from you. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to point out is that the RIM sample push application is *ridiculously overcomplicated*. The username and password you are referring to are used to authenticate against the `sample push initiator` web application which runs on your tomcat server. It doesn't matter what you put in there, they are not used for authentication. I can only assume they were added to show you that you *can* send a username and password to a web based service.

The **only** things you need in your BlackBerry app to register for the push service are:

- Push Application ID (e.g. 2672-c870l6c924r1i298O4o33cc5391y0e75134)
- Push Port (e.g. 31940)
- BlackBerry Push Server URL (e.g. http://pushapi.eval.blackberry.com)

The `port is unavailable` message you're receiving is probably because the device you're using has not been provisioned for BlackBerry Internet Services (BIS). Make sure it has a SIM with an active BlackBerry data plan.

Comment: how to change the eval credentials to productions ?

Comment: Just change the Push Server URL within the app.

Comment: I agree with you @donturner. I anyway solved the problem by writing my own push client without bothering about configuring Sample push application. I was totally confused with the push protocol and push client, why push client needs to know the push initiator URL. Client needs just that information you specified, nothing else.

Comment: Upgrading from Push Essentials to Push Plus, I think you need to contact RIM. Just changing Push server URL may not suffice.

Comment: Do not post new questions in comments. Post a new question with the details of your issue.