# Blackberry Push Client Application Blackberry Registration failed

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde, blackberry-push

I am quite new to blackberry application development and i need to create an application which can receive push notifications.

I have created the application and was trying to use xtify for pushing notifications to devices.

I have registered with rim for the push evaluation and got the credentials like url,app id,password etc.

When the application launches , i create a new thread to perform the push registration process.
I try to send an http Get request to the push evaluation url for registering the device.When i try to open a connection,i get the io exception,invalid url parameter.

I am using a wifi connection for network connectivity in  device. I donot have a sim in the device.
The url is

```
http://cpXXX.pushapi.eval.blackberry.com/mss/PD_subReg?serviceid='My Application Id'&osversion='My OS Version'&model='Device Model';deviceside=false;ConnectionType=mds-public
```

Below is the code i use to send the request.

```java
    DataBuffer buffer = new DataBuffer(256, false);
    httpUrl = "http://cpXXX.pushapi.eval.blackberry.com/mss/PD_subReg?serviceid='My Application Id'&osversion='My OS Version'&model='Device Model';deviceside=false;ConnectionType=mds-public"

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    HttpConnection httpConn = null;
    try {
        httpUrl ;
        conn = Connector.open(httpUrl);
        if (conn instanceof HttpConnection) {
            httpConn = (HttpConnection) conn;
            int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
            if(responseCode == 200){
                inputStream = httpConn.openInputStream();
                int length = inputStream.read(buffer.getArray());
                buffer.setLength(length);
                String response = new String( buffer.getArray(), buffer.getArrayStart(), buffer.getArrayLength() );
                return response;
            }else { 
                throw new IOException( "Http error: " + responseCode);
            }
        }

        else {
            throw new IOException("Can not make HTTP connection for URL '"
                    + httpUrl + "'");
        }

    }
    finally {
        if (httpConn != null) {
            try {
                httpConn.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        close(conn, inputStream, null);
    }
```

Please help me. I am waiting for replies. I have been stuck with this for days. Please advice. Anyone have idea where i can get a documentation for the device registration api ??

Comment: first you search on stackoverflow. you will get too much answers for this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Blackberry+Push+Client+Application+Blackberry+Registration+failed

Comment: Hi @Black Pearl , i been going through stackoverflow searching for a solution, and havent found any.

Comment: did you check this ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049705/cannot-register-in-sample-blackberry-push-application

Comment: http://rincethomas.blogspot.in/2012/07/push-notification-in-blackberry.html

Comment: @Black Pearl yeah.. i did check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049705/cannot-register-in-sample-blackberry-push-application

Comment: I have implemented in a similar way mentioned in the blog except that i use a wifi connection. and the url will be like http://cpXXX.pushapi.eval.blackberry.com/mss/PD_subReg?serviceid='My Application Id'&osversion='My OS Version'&model='Device Model';interface=wifi

Comment: @BlackPearl the problem is right now, i'm only having a wifi connectivity. There is no sim with BIS activation . Is BIS necessary to register the device ?? While trying , I am getting DNS exception

Comment: ohhh.... You need a sim and a BIS connection for registering your devise.

Comment: @BlackPearl i think  BIS connection needed only to receive the push notifications , because RIM uses BIS to send the notifications to the device?? Is it necessary to use the BIS for device registration also??

Comment: yes @Deepak, if you need to register, you have a active BIS connection

Comment: @BlackPearl , Thanks for helping me. I will try it and post the results. Can i get your mail id??

Comment: @BlackPearl , thanks a lot for spending time with me, i activated BIS plan on a sim and tried it. Its wroking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx to the advice of @Black Pearl , I was able to resolve the issue. Inorder for the blackberry registration to work , you need an active BIS connection. I had been trying it with wifi connectivity and hence it was not working.